# Source - ODBC is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssis-2016

After deploying an SSIS package from a development server to another environment, execution and validation of the package fail with the following error:

> Error: The version of #5) Source - ODBC - Greenplum [object name] is not compatible with this version of the DataFlow

The SQL Server and Greenplum ODBC driver versions are the same on all relevant servers.  The servers are running SQL Server 2016, and SQL Server Management Studio 2017 is being used to deploy the package between servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying the package with SQL Server Management Studio 2016 resolved the issue.